# How to handle scheduler synchronization over multiple instances using Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, scheduler

If application is deployed on multiple server and one instance is executing the scheduler then scheduler should not initiate from other instances.

Comment: Use Quartz with a persistence storage and use [`@DisallowConcurrentExecution`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html) to disallow concurrent execution.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the response.We are using Cron..can it be implemented with cron ?

Comment: Cron as in the command line cron or a cron expression (as those are quite different things).

Comment: Cron Expressions

Comment: And why wouldn't a cron expression work with Quartz?

Comment: It is not working..can you help through some code snippet?t

Comment: What isn't working? Read uyp on how quartz works and how to define a quartz based cron-trigger.